# typo3 issue with gifbuilder; image is white or error occured

Tags: typo3

i try to generate an image with gifbuilder in Typo3 but I don't get the expected result. For example this code only shows a white Image although the used image is existing.

```
marks {
    # Das Datum ausgeben
  DATUM = TEXT
  DATUM.data = date:d. m. Y

    # Das Logo ausgeben
  LOGO = IMAGE
  LOGO.file = fileadmin/images/logo.png
  LOGO.file.height = 121

    # Den Trailer erstellen
  TRAILER = IMAGE
  TRAILER.file = GIFBUILDER
  TRAILER.file {
    XY = 731,143
    backColor = white

    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file = fileadmin/images/trailerbild.jpg
      file.width = 731
      file.offset 0,-180
    }
  }
}
```

If I use this code, I get an error: *Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2015032721120260395447*

```
marks {
    # Das Datum ausgeben
  DATUM = TEXT
  DATUM.data = date:d. m. Y

    # Das Logo ausgeben
  LOGO = IMAGE
  LOGO.file = fileadmin/images/logo.png
  LOGO.file.height = 121

    # Den Trailer erstellen
  TRAILER = IMAGE
  TRAILER.file = GIFBUILDER
  TRAILER.file {
    XY = 731,143
    backColor = white

    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file = fileadmin/images/trailerbild.jpg
      file.width = 731
      file.offset 0,-180
    }

    20 = IMAGE
    20 {
      file = fileadmin/images/trailer_overlay.png
      mask = fileadmin/images/trailer_mask.png
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Did you check the image-processing config using the install-tool (Install-Tool -> Test Setup)? Check if ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick, gdlib etc. is available on your system and properly configured.

Comment: There is only an issue with niceText.at GDLib

Comment: fix the issue first. question: which one of the image renderings does not work? you are writing that you get an error - what error (add as many infos as possible).

Comment: You find the error above. The image 10 is ignored while rendering. If I add the 20th, I get the error

Comment: did you find anything in the log-files? -> `typo3temp/logs/typo3.log`, apache/php logs etc?

Comment: In the error_log from php is nothing. The typo3.log says the same: Oops, an error occurred. Component is TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.ContentObject.Exception.

Comment: I once had similar issues with TYPO3 6.2 and 7.x. Please check, that you have set `[GFX][gdlib_png] = 1` in the install tool. That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you, I only get the error msg above. I've set up a new ubuntu vm server and installed typo3 7.1.0 again. @fateddy There I don't get any hint in the system check but I get the same error. @derhansen `[GFX][gdlib_png] = 1` doesn't change anything.